# BdMO 2014 - Chattagong Regional Q. 6

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> $\triangle ABC$ is a right angle triangle with $\angle A = 90 ^o$. $AD \perp BC$. $P$ is a point on the circumcircle of $\triangle ADC$ such that $PC \perp BC\; \text{and}\; AP = AD$. Given that $BP^2 = 350$. Find the area of $\triangle ABC$

I am missing something. I know This is gonna be easy. Any hint will be help full. 
[image]

Comment: Can you mark the point D on your figure? Are you sure $AD \perp AC$?

Comment: I think is $AD \perp DC$.

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento $AD \perp BC$ sorry

Comment: @foofaafuu added.. I missed that first

Comment: I tracked down the question. The problem stated here is incomplete - there is also the condition $AP = AD,$ and in fact it's $340,$ not $350$. Anyway, this makes the problem more or less trivial

Comment: @cats Oh I missied that :(  ... And also it is not Chittagong Regional ... It is Chattagram Regional :( However those are same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $\alpha=\angle CPD=\angle ABC$ and $r$ the radius of the circle.

Once $AP=AD$ (@cats hint) then the rectangle $ADCP$ is a square and then $\alpha =45$.

So looking to the triangle $CDP$ we get $PC=2r\cos(45) \Rightarrow PC=r\sqrt{2}$ and looking to the triangle $ABC$ we get $AC=2r$ and $BC=2r\sqrt{2}$.

Furthermore $PB^2=PC^2+BC^2 \Rightarrow 350=2r^2+8r^2 \Rightarrow r^2=35$.

$S(ABC)=\frac{AC \cdot AB}{2}=\frac{2r \cdot 2r}{2}=2r^2=2 \cdot35=70$

Comment: Actually I missed the AP = AD part... Then I should have solved this... Nice solution ^_^ (y)

Comment: easiest solution I can see is to note that $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$ and so the area of triangle $ABC$ is $s^2$ while $5s^2 = 350$ (or $340$ if you want)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to determine the area of $\triangle ABC$ with the information given.  $AC$ must be a diameter of the circle since $ADC$ is a right angle, so $CPA$ must also be a right angle.  So $CPAD$ is a rectangle and $|CP|=|AD|.$  This is enough to show that $|BC|^2 + |AD|^2=|PB|^2.$ $BC$ and $AD$ are respectively the hypotenuse and the altitude attached to the right angle of $\triangle ABC$, but knowing the sum of squares of the hypotenuse and altitude of a right triangle is not enough to give you the area.

Comment: the original question also has $AP = AD$